# How to configure Unbound to validate a DNS over TLS server's certificate?

Tags: dns, unbound

I have configured Unbound to use DNS over TLS using the following configuration. How can I configure Unbound to validate the upstream certificate against a hostname?

```
forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-addr: 1.1.1.1@853
        forward-addr: 1.0.0.1@853
        forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1111@853
        forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1001@853
        forward-tls-upstream: yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug report for adding support for validating the upstream DNS server's certificate was resolved on April 19, 2018.

Adapting the example from [comment 9](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/bugs-script/show_bug.cgi?id=658#c9):

```
server:
        tls-cert-bundle: "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-addr: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com
        forward-addr: 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com
        forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com
        forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
        forward-tls-upstream: yes
```

There's also an explanation of how it works - the hashtag name allows for
the tls authentication name to be set for stub-zones and with unbound-control forward control commands.  There should be no spaces around the '@' and '#'.

Comment: Credit to @jwh, but apparently I'm not able to edit their answer to include an example.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can not. There is an unresolved bug for this:

[unbound using TLS in a forwarding configuration does not verify the server's certificate](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/bugs-script/show_bug.cgi?id=658)

So with Unbounds DNS over TLS your requests can be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

The bug for "unbound using TLS in a forwarding configuration does not verify the server's certificate" was resolved on 19 Apr 2018:

> TLS authentication for forwarders.
>
> The syntax is forward-addr:
>   [@port][#tls-authentication-name] And the ca bundle can be
>   set with: tls-cert-bundle: "ca-bundle.pem" (or the ca-bundle.crt
>   file).
>
> Example server:   tls-cert-bundle: "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
>   forward-zone:   name: "."   forward-tls-upstream: yes   forward-addr:
>   9.9.9.9@853#dns.quad9.net   forward-addr: 1.1.1.1@853#cloudflare-dns.com
>
> The hashtag name trick makes it so that the tls authentication name
>   can also be set for eg. stub-zones and with unbound-control forward
>   control commands.  It was also easier in the code.  There should be no
>   spaces around the '@' and '#'.
>
> The port number is [...] 853 when you specify a tls authname.  (And
>   still 53 for others).

Ref: [comment 9](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/bugs-script/show_bug.cgi?id=658#c9).

Comment: As is, its a bit of a link only answer. It would be useful to integrate some of the information from the appropriate email into your post.